# Update function for NodeSocket?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, add-on, compositing-nodes

How do I set a callback for socket input change (value or link change) when having a custom node? 
I have a socket defined like:

```
self.node_tree.inputs.new("NodeSocketFloat", "Start")
```

Is there a way to call an update function such as when working with a Property, for example:

```
bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Value", description="Trololo..",default=0.0, update=update_effect)
```

Now it seems like the whole compositor gets refreshed when changing the socket value but I need to actually compute something not related to the linked group nodes to the changed socket just like when the property gets changed and calls the `update_effect`.
Thanks.

EDIT:
I have tried defining [`socket_value_update`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html?highlight=node#bpy.types.Node.socket_value_update) function which doesn't seem to work at all. [`update`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html?highlight=node#bpy.types.Node.update) function does what I need but only when a link to the socket is removed/added, not when the value changes.

EDIT2: I've opened this issue [here](https://developer.blender.org/T67649).